# How to remove elements before or after space in an R vector

Tags: r

I have around 200 .txt files of song lyrics that have a format similar to this

```
Useless info
useless info


First Verse
First Verse

Second Verse
Second Verse


useless info
```

and I would like to read all of them into R to do some text mining. My thought is to read them in with `readLines` and then remove elements from that vector before the first and last blank lines. This is what I have so far.

```
lines <- readLines(txtfile)
lines

> "Useless info" "useless info" "" "" "First Verse" "First Verse" 
> "" "" "Second Verse" "Second Verse" "" "" "useless info"
```

If I were to hard code the solution, I would just have elements `lines[5:6,8:9]` and assign it to a new variable, but because the song lyrics sometimes have two verses and sometimes three, I was hoping there was a solution that would take out the elements before the first double "" and after the last double ""

If I am going about this wrong and someone has a better idea, I am more than happy to hear it as well!

UPDATE: The lines "Useless info" don't literally say "Useless info", they are the file paths to the lyrics and tags, so for analytical reasons, they are useless to me

Comment: try `lines[nzchar(lines)]`

Comment: Is that a fixed string or is different in each case

Comment: It's different in each case. Sometimes there are two lines of useless info, and sometimes there are three at the beginning of the document, but always one at the end

Comment: Can you check whether the solution I posted  works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```r
sapply(strsplit(paste(lines, collapse = "&esc;"), "(&esc;){2,3}"), 
       function(x) paste0(gsub("&esc;", "\n", x[-c(1, length(x))]), collapse = "\n\n"))
# [1] "First Verse\nFirst Verse\n\nSecond Verse\nSecond Verse"
```

Which when printed or written to a text file gives

```
First Verse
First Verse

Second Verse
Second Verse
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a grouping variable with `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- split(lines, rleid(nzchar(lines)))
lst2 <- lst1[-c(1, length(lst1))]
out  <- unlist(lst2[sapply(lst2, function(x) all(nzchar(x)))], use.names = FALSE)
out
#[1] "First Verse"  "First Verse"  "Second Verse" "Second Verse"
```

#### data

```
lines <- c("Useless info", "useless info", "", "", "First Verse", "First Verse", 
"", "", "Second Verse", "Second Verse", "", "", "useless info"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution may depend on how your further processing would look like, e.g. whether you would like to keep verse information (@akrun's `rleid` would be useful there), collapse all into one string, etc..
Based on the file layout you could remove the first non-empty elements, and the last element, and then all the empty elements in between:

```
# optional: read file _textfile_ with `data.table::fread`
lines <- data.table::fread(text="textfile", header=FALSE, sep=NULL, colClasses='character')$V1

first.empty <- which(!nzchar(lines))[1] # determine where to start

lines <- lines[first.empty:(length(lines)-1)] # also remove last element
lines <- lines[nzchar(lines)] # remove empty elements
lines
# or with `magrittr` pipe:
lines[first.empty:(length(lines)-1)] %>% .[nzchar(.)]
```